# Apache conf: how to specify subdomain in <Directory /path/to/subdomain> when using mod_vhost_alias for wildcard virtual hosts

Tags: mod-rewrite, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain, apache-2.2

To start with, we wanted a request to `*.example.com` to be handled by a corresponding `/var/www/*/` directory, and we have got this working by using `mod_vhost_alias` with `VirtualDocumentRoot`, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now we want to expand on this shared configuration by applying the same RewriteRules to all subdomains / directories - from within the vhost configuration's `<Directory>` block - but we do not know how to reference the subdomain / directory.

We're basically trying to do something like this (note the use of %1, which doesn't work in this case):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/

    <Directory /var/www/%1>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule     ^about/?$       index.php?view=about
            RewriteRule     ^settings/?$    index.php?view=settings
            RewriteRule     ^support/?$     index.php?view=support
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok we've managed to get this to work. All that was needed was a minor tweak of the `<Directory>` path (namely using the * wildcard instead of %1), removing the ^ characters in the RewriteRules' patterns, and adding a leading / in the substitution strings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/

    <Directory /var/www/*>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule     about/?$       /index.php?view=about
        RewriteRule     settings/?$    /index.php?view=settings
        RewriteRule     support/?$     /index.php?view=support
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now for the sake of complying with ServerFault's policy (as well as Google's indexing), I'm marking this question as answered, but I must emphasise that we couldn't have done this without the patient help from *thumbs* in *#httpd* on *irc.freenode.net*

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `<Directory>` in this case.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^/about/?$       /index.php?view=about
    RewriteRule     ^/settings/?$    /index.php?view=settings
    RewriteRule     ^/support/?$     /index.php?view=support
</VirtualHost>
```

If you've got something other than a `Rewrite` that needs to be done, for instance, access controls, add a `<Location>` block instead of a `<Directory>` block:

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks Shane. I tried this but I get a 404 error. I checked my access.log and it seems that the URLs are not being re-written correctly. For example, `http://foo.example.com/about/` is being re-written to `http://foo.example.com/about/index.php?view=about` instead of `http://foo.example.com/index.php?view=about` - and I also checked the error.log and it says "File does not exist: /htdocs". Any ideas?